# PHP: Interhited method calling a method in the parent class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

```
class Person {
    function foo() {
        // Code.
    }

    function bar() {
        $this->foo();
    }
}

class Pete extends Person {

}
```

When `Person::foo()` is called from within `Person::bar()` in the above example, the call is happening within the `Person` class. Hence, I *could* make the visibility of `Person::foo()` `private`.

As you'll be aware, when I extend the `Person` class, `Person::foo()` and `Person::bar()` are inherited by the child class `Pete`. Hence, the inherited method `Pete::bar()` calls `Pete::foo()`.

**My question**

From within `Pete::bar()`, is the call to `Pete::foo()` considered to come from a) the parent class or b) the child class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From within Pete::bar(), is the call to Pete::foo() considered to come from a) the parent class or b) the child class?

Neither. Technically, `foo()` does not exist in class `Pete`. It exists in `Person` and is inherited by `Pete`. Regardless, *who's calling* the method is based on the invocation.

For example:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->foo(); // invocation by `Person` object
$pete = new Pete();
$pete->foo(); // invocation by `Pete` object
```

> I'm trying to determine method visibility

If you want these methods to be inherited, you are limited to `public` or `protected`. `private` methods are not inherited. I would encourage you to read more about [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

As noted in [deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28967485/164998), you can make methods `private` and access it through another `public` method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So building on your invocation example, imagine if I used the following: `$pete = new Pete(); $pete->bar()` to invoke the `bar()` method. What would happen if a) `foo()` was `private` and b) `foo()` was `protected`? Keep in mind `bar()` calls `foo()`

Comment: As noted in deceze's answer, it would still work for any visibility since `bar()` invokes `foo()` from within the same class.

Comment: So even though the `bar()` method is inherited by `Pete` and is being invoked by the `$pete` object, `bar()` is considered to belong to Person (hence the invocation of `foo()` is happening from within `Person`)?

Answer (score 2):

If a method has a visibility of `private`, then all code which explicitly calls it must reside in the same class definition. That's pretty much the rule, nothing more, nothing less. Indirect calls through inheritance work just fine.

```
class Foo {
    private function bar() { }
    public function baz() { /* here be dragons */ }
}

class Child extends Foo { }
```

In the `Child` class you *may not* write `$this->bar()`. It will fail. The `bar` method is `private` to the class `Foo`, no other code may call it. You *may* call `baz` though anytime from anywhere, it is `public` and can be called from other code. **Whatever `baz` does internally is none of your concern.** If `baz` calls `bar` internally, that's fine. Its code resides in `Foo` and therefore can call `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

If you make it private, `Person::foo` can only be called from Person

```
class Person {
    //Can only be called inside of Person
    private function foo() {
        // Code.
    }

    public function bar() {
        //can be called
        $this->foo();
    }
}
```

You can still call `bar`, since it is public. `bar` still can access to `foo`, because it is a method from `Person`.

You can not call `foo` from `Pete`, since it is only visible in Person.

```
class Pete extends Person {
    public function doSomething() {
        //Works because bar itself calls foo
        $this->bar();
    }
}
```

If you want to call `foo` directly fom `Pete` or override it, you need to declare it `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: Are you confusing `foo` and `bar` by any chance in that last example?

Comment: `private` or `protected`?

Comment: @deceze yes, thanks for this hint. Foo, bar, baz is always confusing :)